# How to wait until thread is completed in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have this method updatePosts() that needs to run inside of a thread. it looks like this

```
public void updatePosts(){
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            posts.addAll(pholder.fetchPosts());
            System.out.println("size of posts is " + posts.size());

            // UI elements should be accessed only in
            // the primary thread, so we must use the
            // handler here.

        }
    }.start();
}
```

It is literally updating the List called "posts". I have this in my onCreate. The problem is, since it is running in a separate thread, it does not complete before my ImageAdapter needs to use the "posts" List.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updatePosts();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, posts));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

What options do I have to ensure that the updatePosts can finish before the ImageAdapter get created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an AsyncTask or any other mechanism that lets you offload a task to a background thread with a callback to the UI on completion.

```
private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Post>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Post> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO
        return posts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Post> posts) {
        // TODO: update UI
    }
}
```

Another option is to use RxJava,

```
        Observable
                .fromCallable(new Callable<List<Post>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Post> call() throws Exception {
                        // TODO: get posts
                        return posts;
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(posts -> {
                    // TODO: update UI
                }, throwable -> {
                    // TODO
                })
```

Comment: That actually works perfectly, but a new question arises from this? Can I use this inside of an ImageAdapter? I set up a new BackgroundTask, but my getView returns the imageView before my Background Task finishes executing?

Comment: Wait to initialize your adapter until you have the data to populate it, there's no point to do it before the data is ready. Launch your background task in your fragment instead of the adapter and when to task completes set up your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Handler.

```
private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
private MyHandler mHandler;
private List<YourData> posts;
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

 GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
 mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, posts)；
 gridview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
 }); 
 mHandler = new MyHandler(this);
 updatePosts();
}
public void updatePosts(){ 
new Thread(){
    public void run(){ 
        posts.addAll(pholder.fetchPosts()); 
        System.out.println("size of posts is " + posts.size());
        if (mHandler != null) {
          mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(1));
         }
        // UI elements should be accessed only in 
        // the primary thread, so we must use the 
        // handler here. 

    } 
}.start();
}
private static class MyHandler extend Handler{
 private WeakReference<Your Activity name> outer;
 public MyHandler(Your Activity name activity){
     outer = new WeakReference<>(activity);
 }
 @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg){
     switch(msg.what){
         case 1:
             if(outer.get()!=null){
                 outer.get().mAdapter.refresh(outer.get().posts);
             }
         break;
         default:break;
     }
 }
}
```

And in your ImageAdapter,you need add a method:

```
 public void refresh(List<YourData> dataSet){
  this.dataSet = dataSet;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```